# MOST efficient way of reading data from oracle using pyspark or sqoop import?

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, sqoop

We have a requirement to read data from the oracle table to spark jobs(dim and fct running on hdfs). They both read different columns from the same table.

Total number of records in the table = ~13M

To optimize the above process, we came up with two options:

1. sqoop import table from oracle and store it on hdfs - pyspark(dim & fct jobs) reads relative columns from hdfs.

   - Cons: 
     Resource intensive, additional sqoop-job, load on the edge node.
2. Using pyspark dataframe api make a connection to oracle using jdbc.

   - Read-only required columns to dims(4).
     &
   - Read the required columns for fcts(12)
   - Cons: It makes connections twice for two jobs.
   - Pros: Easy maintenance, no dependency on sqoop, No load on edge node, resource-friendly.

Which is the most efficient option? or do you think there is any other better option?

Comment: So, how does the 'con' of option 1 (pulling a lot of unnecessary data across the network) compare to the 'con' of option 2 (making another db connection)?  And what are the "pros" for option 1?  And you have a lot of very nice "pros" listed for option 2.  Based on what you've posted, the choice looks rather obvious to me.

Comment: pro's for option-1: since we pull all the data onto HDFS, reading becomes easier for spark. But as you mentioned in order to achieve 'pros' for options-1, we have to pull a lot of unnecessary data across the network, btw you made a good point. So far im thinking option-2 is a good idea but waiting on others to chip in.

Comment: Sqoop and Spark both use JDBC, by the way. Both will scale out multiple tasks to read as much data as you tell them. Sqoop requires a simple CLI, but Spark requires more tuning... Neither run load on an edge node

Comment: Also fact tables for joins are brutally slow in Hive or HDFS. Try remapping data into Hbase or Kudu and it'd be much quicker